# Obtaining an IPv6 prefix via Prefix Delegation in Xenial

Tags: ipv6, dhcpv6

I want to configure an Ubuntu (Xenial) box as an IPv4 and IPv6 router. (I have IPv4 working already.)

I intend to use dnsmasq to distribute globally routable IPv6 addresses via RA. However, to do that, I first need to get the Ubuntu box acting as the router to fetch a prefix via the WAN interface and to assign it to the LAN interface.

What's the best way to do this in Xenial?

I can find [old instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/742792/how-do-i-deploy-ipv6-within-a-lan-using-a-debian-based-router-and-prefix-delegat) that involve using the WIDE DHCPv6 client, but it appears that the [`wide-dhcpv6-client`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wide-dhcpv6-client&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) package in Xenial is from 2008 and upstream over on SourceForge doesn't have anything more recent, either. It seems scary to use network-facing software that's written in C and has been abandoned by upstream for years.

As of Xenial, what's the recommended way of fetching a Prefix Delegation prefix via the WAN interface and assigning it to the LAN interface?

(In case it matters, the ISP says that it hands out prefixes of /56 from which the customer's router is supposed to prepare potentially multiple /64 subnets.)

Comment: The best guide I've found so far is https://hveem.no/using-dnsmasq-for-dhcpv6 which still uses the abandoned wide-dhcpv6-client package. I used AppArmor to confine the process.